# replace xml/svg element attribute for specific element only

Tags: php, xml, svg, str-replace

I have 'XML` like this,

```
<text>
    <tspan fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)'>abc</tspan>
</text>
<rect fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)'></rect>
```

I am trying to replace `rgba(` with `rgb(`, but its replacing all instances occur in data. I just want to replace all the instances for `tspan` tag only.
I tried `str_replace` but replacing all instances into data.

Output should look like this

```
<text>
    <tspan fill='rgb(0,0,0,0)'>abc</tspan>
</text>
<rect fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)'></rect>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regExp:

```
rgba(?=(.*)<\/tspan>)
```

[Tested Here - RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/vY2bW6/1)

```
$re = "/rgba(?=(.*)<\\/tspan>)/"; 
$str = "<text><tspan stroke='' opacity='' fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)'>abc</tspan><tspan fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)'><h1>anything</h1></tspan></text><rect fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)'></rect>"; 
$subst = "rgb"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You still can use str_replace, but use as 'find' parameter a bit longer string:

```
str_replace("<tspan fill='rgba(0,0,0,0)", "<tspan fill='rgb(0,0,0,0)", $your_string);
```

But be careful, it is not the best way to do that on big amounts of data.

Comment: there are some dynamic elements between <tspan. like `<tspan stroke='' opacity='' fill=''>` so i dont think so this will work